# I need to use a temporary attribute I created in my Select Statement in order to use it in a Where statement?

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

I used a view to get the right answer but I want it in one SQL statement, also I was wondering if there was a way to do it without projecting out the tables again.

So can I `COUNT(OW_OWNERNO) AS NO_HOUSES` and use the `NO_HOUSES` in my where clause? Is there a way to define it as such.

This statement is trying to calculate how many houses the people in the data base own and project only those who have more than one home.

```
CREATE VIEW NUMHOUSE AS
SELECT OW_FIRSTNAME, OW_LASTNAME, **COUNT(OW_OWNERNO) AS NO_HOUSES**
FROM (rentproperty JOIN OWNER ON RP_OW_OWNERNO = OW_OWNERNO)
WHERE RP_TYPE = 'House'
GROUP BY OW_OWNERNO;

SELECT * FROM NUMHOUSE
```

WHERE NO_HOUSES > 1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways.  The first one uses a having clause suggested by Fabio.

```
SELECT OW_FIRSTNAME, OW_LASTNAME, COUNT(OW_OWNERNO) AS NO_HOUSES
FROM (rentproperty JOIN OWNER ON RP_OW_OWNERNO = OW_OWNERNO)
WHERE RP_TYPE = 'House'
GROUP BY OW_OWNERNO
having no_houses > 1  -- note some dbs might not let you use an alias here
```

This one uses a subquery

```
select * from (
SELECT OW_FIRSTNAME, OW_LASTNAME, COUNT(OW_OWNERNO) AS NO_HOUSES
FROM (rentproperty JOIN OWNER ON RP_OW_OWNERNO = OW_OWNERNO)
WHERE RP_TYPE = 'House'
GROUP BY OW_OWNERNO
) temp
where no_houses > 1
```

They work equally well.

Comment: Thanks @Fabio and I needed that having clause, I just didn't understand the context. That's exactly what I wanted to know; if there was a way around not being able to reference an alias in the where clause. All sorted code is working. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks @Dan Bracuk and I needed that having clause, I just didn't understand the context. That's exactly what I wanted to know; if there was a way around not being able to reference an alias in the where clause. All sorted code is working. Thanks again

Comment: Please fix the 1st query to valid SQL: `HAVING COUNT(OW_OWNERNO) > 1`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`

Example

```
SELECT * FROM NUMHOUSE HAVING COUNT(NO_HOUSES) > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was wondering if there was a way of altering the code so I don't have to use a VIEW?

Comment: @Ryan just run this query direcly, you don't need view

Comment: Why do you think you need a view?

Comment: I created the view NUMHOUSES, if I run SELECT * FROM NUMHOUSE WHERE NO_HOUSES > 1; it gives me the correct output, but ID like one query statement for example:

Comment: SELECT OW_FIRSTNAME, OW_LASTNAME, **COUNT(OW_OWNERNO) AS NO_HOUSES**
FROM (rentproperty JOIN OWNER ON RP_OW_OWNERNO = OW_OWNERNO)
WHERE RP_TYPE = 'House' AND NO_HOUSES > 1
GROUP BY OW_OWNERNO;

Comment: This is not valid standard SQL